# Breezejs error when loading an entity with related data

Tags: c#, javascript, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I'm no doubt missing something obvious here so perhaps the collective power of the internet can point it out to me.

I have a code first database structure, consisting of Users, Groups and a GroupUsers table to link the two (EF can handle n-n relationships itself but breezejs needs the table explicitly https://stackoverflow.com/a/13636530/249813).

I'm then trying to load users via Breezejs at the client. This works fine when a user is not a member of any groups, but fails when they are with the following message.

```
object #<object> has no method getproperty
```

Could anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Database:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GroupUser> GroupUsers { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupUser> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupUser> Users { get; set; } 
}

public class GroupUser
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Group")]
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Javascript

```
var serviceName = '/breeze/admin';
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Users');

manager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(function(data) {
        //do something good
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        //do something bad.
    });
```

JSON produced by Breeze API controller when user isn't a member of a group (Works fine)

```
[
    {
        $id: "1",
        $type: "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_41E3B55B982835BEAAA863D9A28B60E1A07D42FBEB52862F05DCD4BAE3F6171C, EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-MyBreezeTest",
        Groups: [ ],
        Id: "665b2a59-f1ae-41c6-8d6b-df758713db01",
        Name: "Me",
        Email: "me@example.com",
        IsActive: true,
        IsAdmin: true
    }
]
```

JSON produced by Breeze API controller when user IS a member of a group (Fails)

```
[
    {
        $id: "1",
        $type: "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_41E3B55B982835BEAAA863D9A28B60E1A07D42FBEB52862F05DCD4BAE3F6171C, EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-MyBreezeTest",
        Groups: [
            {
                $id: "2",
                $type: "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.GroupUser_144E644846F6E074946B6DFE31A643AFBBDA0EF263BEBCAA9A6A12E67649A7CF, EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-MyBreezeTest",
                Group: {
                    $id: "3",
                    $type: "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Group_4EDDE8FACA0560ADBB390090E3A6A147D06867A4A693B111AECF35D2CE7E458C, EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-MyBreezeTest",
                    Users: [
                        {
                            $ref: "2"
                        }
                    ],
                    Id: "86365a48-6f45-4614-b0b0-8011ec0e0d77",
                    Name: "Test Group"
                },
                User: {
                    $ref: "1"
                },
                Id: "952faa7b-658d-4e12-8f18-dc9b0898d684",
                UserId: "665b2a59-f1ae-41c6-8d6b-df758713db01",
                GroupId: "86365a48-6f45-4614-b0b0-8011ec0e0d77"
            }
        ],
        Id: "665b2a59-f1ae-41c6-8d6b-df758713db01",
        Name: "Me",
        Email: "me@example.com",
        IsActive: true,
        IsAdmin: true
    }
]
```

**Edit For Future Readers**

Margabit's answer below correctly identifies the problem, however for ease of reference the simplest way to solve this is not do this in the breeze controller:

```
var context = new MyContext();
```

but instead do this

```
var context = _myEFContextProvider.Context;
```

Since EFContextProvider will disable proxy creation and lazy loading on it's own instance and allow you to keep your **virtual** and avoid globally disabling lazy loading in the context constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be using Lazy Loading in EF. This is why you have Dynamic Proxies in the navigation properties.

In  Breeze documentation says that Lazy Loading is not an option for Breeze:

> **Lazy loading**
>
> On several occasions we’ve alluded to the possibility
>   that a related entity exists in remote storage but is not presently in
>   cache. Breeze navigation properties only return entities that are in
>   cache.
>
> In some systems, a navigation property would automatically fetch the
>   related entities from remote storage if they were not already in
>   cache. This process is often called “lazy loading” or “deferred
>   loading” because related entities are only loaded into cache when
>   requested.
>
> Lazy loading is not a Breeze option. Breeze expects you to load
>   related entities explicitly. You can load them either directly by
>   querying for them or indirectly as a byproduct of another query.

So you will need to disable Lazy Load and load the `Groups` and `Type` entities explicitly.

You can remove the Lazy Loading by removing the `virtual` in the navigation properties (just the ones that you don't want to load) or globally by setting in the context:

```
  this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

You can include the navigation properties by:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<YourEntity> Orders() {
    return _contextProvider.Context.YourEntities.Include("Groups").Include("Type");
}
```

Or by loading them in the Query from JavaScript:

```
EntityQuery.from("YourEntities")
.expand("Groups", "Type");
```

References:

[EFContextProvider](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider)

[Navigation Properties](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties)

Comment: I tried disabling lazy loading via the configuration after reading that very piece of documentation and it still didn't work. However either disabling proxy creation completely, or removing virtual on the navigation properties works a charm. Thankyou.

Comment: The other thing that works wonders is using  EFContextProvider.Context instead of creating a new one. Which seems remarkably obvious in the cold harsh light of the morning. Presumably, because EFContextProvider configures things correctly