# How to define Matrix/Link/Cross Table joins in BreezeJS Metadata?

Tags: javascript, breeze, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get breeze working with hand generated Metadata, but I can't seem to find documentation covering navigation properties through matrix tables.

the data model is:

```
Organization
PK:OrganizationID

User
PK:UserID
```

The table that joins them is:

```
User_Organization
PK:UserOrganizationID
FK:OrganizationID
FK:UserID
```

When I retrieve an Organization I want it to have a property "users" which contains an array of User objects.

How do I define this and specify the matrix table in Breeze Metadata, seeing as User does not have an organizationID?

** update

My primary problem is that I'm linking Breeze to Sequelize, so I need to be able to manage this all through the metadata if possible. The first answer below from @Jeremy-Danyow solves the problem with client side code, but I'm looking for a way to present the final object graph to breeze as part of the metadata.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Many-to-many relations in Breeze](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636528/many-to-many-relations-in-breeze)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question might be a duplicate of [Many-to-many relations in Breeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636528/many-to-many-relations-in-breeze).  There is useful information in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13636530/725866) there as well as the comments on the answer.

That said, I want to propose a work-around for this part of your question:

> *When I retrieve an Organization I want it to have a property "users" which contains an array of User objects.*

If you were to configure your metadata the [supported way](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/presenting-many-many) you could add a read-only "users" property to your organization entity like this:

```
function Organization() { }

Organization.prototype.users = function () {
    return this.userOrganizations().map(function(userOrganization) { return userOrganization.user() });
};

store.registerEntityTypeCtor('Organization', Organization);
```

This uses the "Add methods to the constructor" approach documented [here](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/extending-entities).

---

**Edit**

Sounds like breeze-sequelize support is in the works and will be released soon.  See [here](https://twitter.com/wardbell/status/551102256158760960) and [here](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.node/tree/master/breeze-sequelize).  If you can afford to wait a little bit you'll have less friction getting this going.

Comment: Thanks for that, and the references - once of them explains something I'd missed, that I needed to explicitly declare the link tables and manually produce the joined result.  I've added some clarification to my original question.

Comment: @TobyTremayne- updated my answer to include some exciting news on the breeze-sequelize front.

Comment: DOH- just realized it's YOUR twitter post I linked to so you already know what I posted in the edit... sorry

Comment: Hehe yeah I'm looking at that project and already integrating what they have. Hopefully I can work with it and the maintainers to finish a solution. Thanks for your help.